# Evaluating a Limit of a Multivar Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate this limit? How to approach it, think about it?

$\lim_{(x, y, z) \to (\pi,0, 1/3)}$ $e^{y^z}tan(xz)$

Comment: The function's continuous everywhere that $\;xz\neq\frac{(2m-1)\pi}2\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ , so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x,y,z) = e^{y^z}\tan(xz)$ is continuous wherever it is defined, and $f$ is defined at $(\pi,0,1/3)$. So, the limit can be evaluated by evaluating $f$ at the point $(\pi,0,1/3)$, which gives $e^{0^{1/3}}\tan(\pi/3) = e \sqrt{3}$.

---

For further detail, let us check that $f$ is indeed continuous. The composition of continuous functions is continuous, and the product of continuous functions is continuous. So, we need to check that the functions $g$ defined by $g(x,y) = x^y$, $h$ defined by $h(x) = e^x$ and $k$ defined by $k(x,y) = \tan(xy)$ are all continuous where they are defined. Then, $f(x,y,z) = g\circ h(y,z) \cdot k(x,z) = e^{y^z}\tan(xz)$ is continuous wherever it is defined, and it is clearly defined at the point $(\pi,0,1/3)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to think about it: the limit of a product is the product of the limits (if they exist). The limit of $f(\text{something})$ is $f$ of the limit, if $f$ is a continuous function. The limit of a sequence of vectors is the vector of limits of the vector coordinates.

Comment: But is tan a continuous function? Aren't there asymptotes? How to reconcile that

Comment: $xz \to \pi/3,$ where $\tan$ is harmless, i.e., continuous.

Comment: I see, so just to clairfy; when dealing with limits of these multivariable functions if it's continuous at the points the variable are approaching, we don't have to worry about it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct